# How to use Vue to create an extension for VSCode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create a vscode extension with Vue using the vscode webview, but when I tried to import the built index.html in my extension, it always tells me to enable javascript. Is there a way to use Vue in a vscode extension or to enable the js in vscode? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but I'm stating to work on something similar and found this repo that helped me get started. https://github.com/leocll/vscode-extension-webview-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it was asked 10 months ago..

Today I faced the same issue. Scripts are disabled by default.

In order to enable them, you need to pass

```
{
    enableScripts: true
}
```

for the parameter called "options" in function vscode.window.createWebviewPanel.

This is what my function call looks like:

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
    'projector',
    'Projector',
    vscode.ViewColumn.One,
    {
        enableScripts: true
    }
);
```

Comment: I already forgot about this whole thing.... But still, thank you!